# columns changing order after opening csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I wrote code to open and get some data from a csv file with pandas.
However, when i tried to open a similar file (just different data), two columns
changed place. 
Like this:

```
   Unnamed: 30  Unnamed: 31    Raw    Filtered  
0  NaN          0.702          1.0    NaN  
1  NaN          0.790          1.0    NaN  
2  NaN          0.877          1.0    NaN  
3  NaN          0.771          1.0    NaN
```

The correct input should be:

```
   Raw    Filtered  
0  0.702  1.0                 
1  0.790  1.0
2  0.877  1.0
3  0.771  1.0
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is because of the code you used to import and likely the separator you used.  Please include the code you used to import.

Comment: Feel free to upvote as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Example 1***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """Raw Filtered
0.702 1.
0.790 1.
0.877 1.
0.771 1."""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep=' ')

     Raw  Filtered
0  0.702       1.0
1  0.790       1.0
2  0.877       1.0
3  0.771       1.0
```

***Example 2***
*Include some inconvenient spaces `' '`*

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """  Raw Filtered
 0.702 1.
 0.790 1.
 0.877 1.
 0.771 1."""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep=' ')

   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Raw  Filtered
0         NaN       0.702  1.0       NaN
1         NaN       0.790  1.0       NaN
2         NaN       0.877  1.0       NaN
3         NaN       0.771  1.0       NaN
```

***Example 3***
*Same inconvenient spaces but with a different import*

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """  Raw Filtered
 0.702 1.
 0.790 1.
 0.877 1.
 0.771 1."""

print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True))

     Raw  Filtered
0  0.702       1.0
1  0.790       1.0
2  0.877       1.0
3  0.771       1.0
```